# Filling a two dimensional array with mysql fetch results in php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, bar-chart

I just had a framework for creating charts and this is how it works normally.

```
$p = new chartphp();
$p->data = array(array(
array("A",2),
array("B",3),
array("C",23),
array("D",10)   
));
$p->chart_type = "bar";
// Common Options
$p->xlabel = "My X Axis";
$p->ylabel = "My Y Axis";
$out = $p->render('c1');
```

This way it works perfectly fine, now I need to get results from a sql query and fill the array.

```
$query ="SELECT t.date AS dates,COUNT(t.id) AS trans FROM Gab AS g, Transaction AS t WHERE t.date BETWEEN '2015-07-30' AND '201-07-10' AND g.TID = '1401009' ORDER BY DATES";
$ask = mysql_query($query) or die("Error");
//Now I try to load the results into the array to be integrated into the API.

$p = new chartphp();
$p->data = array(array(
while($recon = mysql_fetch_array($ask)
{
array($recon['dates'],recon['trans']),
}
));
$p->chart_type = "bar";
// Common Options
$p->xlabel = "My X Axis";
$p->ylabel = "My Y Axis";
$out = $p->render('c1');
```

I tried this but it does not work, the array dont seem to be loaded !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm actually not sure what nesting a `while` like you have would do and I'm unable to experiment at the moment, but something like this should get you in the right direction:

```
$p->data = array(array());
while($recon = mysql_fetch_array($ask))
{
  $p->data[0][] = array($recon['dates'], $recon['trans']);
}
```

Initializing the array and then appending the elements in the loop.